# How to make QTextBrowser scale nicely within QVBoxLayout?

Tags: qt

I'd like to display a list of short html snippets in a scrollable list. Thus i place a QVboxLayout into a QScrollArea and add multiple QTextBrowsers:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QScrollArea scrollArea;
  scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(true);
  QWidget *scrollWidget = new QWidget;
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

  for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    QString text = "some <b>text</b> ";
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++) text += text;

    QTextBrowser *browser = new QTextBrowser();
    QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument(browser);
    doc->setHtml(text);
    browser->setDocument(doc);

    layout->addWidget(browser);
  }

  scrollWidget->setLayout(layout);
  scrollArea.setWidget(scrollWidget);

  scrollArea.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

My problem: The boxes all have the same size. I want them to be as big as necessary, but not bigger. How can i make the textbrowsers to take only as much space as they really need?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution derived from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39839-QTextBrowser-height-adjusted-to-content. Is there a simpler/mor elegant solution?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QShowEvent>
#include <QResizeEvent>

class MyBrowser : public QTextBrowser {
private:
  QTextDocument *doc;

public:
  MyBrowser(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = 0) : QTextBrowser(parent) {
    doc = new QTextDocument(this);
    doc->setHtml(text);
    setDocument(doc);
  }

  void adjust() {
    QMargins margins = contentsMargins();

    int width = size().width() - 
      margins.left() - margins.right() - doc->documentMargin()*2;
    doc->setPageSize(QSizeF(width,-1));

    int height = doc->size().height() + margins.top() + margins.bottom();
    setMaximumHeight(height);
    setMinimumHeight(height);
  }

  void showEvent(QShowEvent *) {
    adjust();
  }

  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) {
    adjust();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QScrollArea scrollArea;
  scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(true);
  QWidget *scrollWidget = new QWidget;
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

  for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    QString text = "some <b>text</b> ";
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++) text += text;

    MyBrowser *browser = new MyBrowser(text, scrollWidget);
    layout->addWidget(browser, 0, 0);
  } 

  scrollWidget->setLayout(layout);
  scrollArea.setWidget(scrollWidget);

  scrollArea.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, no. The problem you face is that QTextEdit derives from QAbstractScrollArea. QAbstractScrollArea::sizeHint() always returns a fixed size of (256,192) pixels - that's why you can't shrink those textboxes any smaller, no matter what size policy you use (excepting QSizePolicy::Ignored, however).

Edit: the only thing I can offer is that you might be able to achieve the same as above by overriding sizeHint() and using a Fixed QSizePolicy.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing

```
layout->addWidget(browser);
```

You should do:

```
layout->addWidget(browser, 0, 0);
```

This will tell QT not to stretch the widget according to its layout.

Comment: Hmm, i don't see any visual change in the result. Using addWidget that way still makes all widgets within the vbox having the same size. Some are bigger than they need to be as they hold few text only, some are not big enough and use a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Try this: browser->setSizePolicy(SizePolicy::Fixed);

Comment: That makes all embedded TextBrowsers be stuck at a fixed 256x256 size which is even worse.

Comment: I actually think that this posting may contain the solution: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39839-QTextBrowser-height-adjusted-to-content